# Find missing data files which are generated every day

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, regex

I receive a lot of data files from my clients which are named in date time format. Example File Name: 20121029153045.txt, which means year 2012, month 10, day 29, hour 15, minutes 30 and seconds 45.

I need to quickly check the dates for which the files are missing or not received. For example, if I receive files for 3 months, starting from August, I need to check which are the missing files from August to October.

What is the quickest way to do this? I am using Windows XP SP 2, 32 bit

Thanks.

Comment: is there any pattern in which they are created? Like are they produced every hour, every minute or so on?

Comment: Usually they are created every day, but I do not receive them every day. My clients mail me once in a week or arbitrarily.

Comment: ahh, so YYYYMMDD is significant here, and need to be in order?

Comment: yes .. These files are in csv format. Inside the file also, each record has date time, which is the 4th comma separated field. Each record has a serial no. which is always incrementing, even across files. This serial no. field is the 5th field. I also need to check for any gaps between the serial no.

Comment: this is a little tricky - I don't think i can solve it myself right now, but am trying to get more information in order to. I have *some* ideas but of course it needs some work

Comment: May be using regular expressions? But how will regular expressions check for continuity across lines and files? May be, we can merge all files and then run some regular expression based check... but I don't know what regular expression can fit this need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a batch file like this:

```
@echo off
for %%m in (08 09 10) do (
    for /l %%d in (1,1,9)   do if not exist 2012%%m0%%d* echo "2012%%m0%%d missing"
    for /l %%d in (10,1,31) do if not exist 2012%%m%%d*  echo "2012%%m%%d missing"
)
```

(but ignore days like 31 September that don't exist :)

Comment: good one.. instead of hardcoding 08 09 10, can I make it start from the 1st date for which file is available and then check up to the last date for which file is available, to find any missing files in between?

Comment: You wanted a *quick* check. How much programming are you willing to do? (And what if the first/last one is missing?)

Comment: By first one and last one, I mean the earliest / latest file available in the folder. By quick, I meant I am willing to do some setup work one time, if the solution can be run quickly and reliably in future.